# Find the least positive integer with remainders 1,2, and 3 when divided by 7,8, and 9 respectively.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

a. Find the least positive integer with remainders 1,2, and 3 when divided by 7,8, and 9 respectively.

The three congruences are

$ x \equiv 1 $ (mod 7)
$ x \equiv 2 $ (mod 8)
$ x \equiv 3 $ (mod 9)

We solve the system by letting

$x =f_1+2f_2+3f_3$

where $f_1.f_2,$ and $f_3$ satisfy

$f_1 \equiv 1 $ (mod 7)
$ f_2 \equiv 0 $ (mod 7)
$ f_3 \equiv 0 $ (mod 7)

$ f_1 \equiv 0 $ (mod 8)
$ f_2 \equiv 1 $ (mod 8)
$ f_3 \equiv 0 $ (mod 8)

$f_1 \equiv 0 $ (mod 9)
$f_2 \equiv 0 $ (mod 9)
$ f_3 \equiv 1 $ (mod 9)

Notice that, under these conditions, by the congruences

$ x =f_1+2f_2+3f_3 \equiv 1$ (mod 7)

$ x =f_1+2f_2+3f_3 \equiv 2$ (mod 8)

$ x =f_1+2f_2+3f_3 \equiv 3$ (mod 9)

To compute $f_1$ we set $f_1 = 8 \times 9 \times b_1$ where $b_1$ satisfies the single congruence.

$72b_1 \equiv 1 $ (mod 7)

$2b_1 \equiv 1 $ (mod 7)

$2b_1-1 = 7k$

$2b_1=7k+1$

$b_1 = \frac{7k+1}{2}$

If we let $k = 1$, then

$b_1 = \frac{7+1}{2}$

$b_1 = \frac{8}{2}$

$b_1 = 4$

Thus $f_1 = 8 \times 9 \times 4 = 288$

Similarly, set $f_2 = 7 \times 9 \times b_2$

$63b_2 \equiv 2$ (mod 8)

$7b_2 \equiv 2$ (mod 8)

$7b_2 - 2 =8k$

$7b_2 =8k+2$

$b_2 = \frac{8k+2}{7}$

If we let $k=5$, then

$b_2 = \frac{40+2}{7}$

$b_2 = \frac{42}{7}$

$b_2 =6$

Thus $f_2 = 7 \times 9 \times 6 =378$

Also, set $f_3 = 7 \times 8 \times b_3$

$56b_3 \equiv 3 $ (mod 9)

$2b_3 - 3 =9k$

$2b_3  =9k +3$

$b_3  =\frac{9k+3}{2}$

If we let $k = 1$, we have $b_3 =\frac{9+3}{2}$

$b_3 =\frac{9+3}{2}$

$b_3 =\frac{12}{2}$

$b_3 =6$

Thus $f_3 = 7 \times 8 \times 6 = 336$

This means $x = 288+2(378)+3(336)$

$x = 288+756 + 1008$

$x=2052$

Since $ 7 \times 8 \times 9 = 504$, we need to reduce $2052$ modulo $504$

I'm supposed to have 498 for 2052 modulo 504, but I'm getting a different number. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: The easy way to do this problem is $-6+(7)(8)(9)$.

Comment: but what if I can't do it like that? I have to use the outline of the pirate problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704815/modular-arithmetic-pirate-problem
the ending is that x = 1367 but it's not the least positive solution. Since $ 7 \times 6 \times 5 = 210$, we reduce 1367 modulo 210 and it does become 107. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong here because I'm supposed to calculate 2052 modulo 504. The 504 is correct.

Comment: Eventually, you will be free of the shackles of homework, and you will be able to do these problems any way you like. When that day comes, you may be happy to know the easy way.

Comment: -__-
2052 modulo 504 is 36. Is that the right answer?

Comment: The right answer is 498 (which is what my formula gives), so there must be something wrong in the calculations that got you to 2052.

Comment: I thought so, but I can't see where I messed up.. since all of the numbers for $b_1, b_2$ and $b_3$ are 4, 6 and 6

Comment: By the way, can you do something about all those \indent things that show up in your post?

Comment: nooooooo... I need a code to indent that would show the indents but I don't know why it's not displaying correctly on here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13471/discussion-between-usukidoll-and-gerry-myerson)

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. Please, take the \indents out, and find some other way to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you do $(7)(9)b_2\equiv2\pmod8$, and then you do $(2)(7)(9)b_2$; you've done the 2 twice. Either do $(7)(9)b_2\equiv1\pmod8$, or do $(7)(9)b_2$.

Comment: $63b_2 \equiv 1 $ (mod 8) ...
$7b_2 \equiv 1$ (mod 8 ) ...
$7b_2 -1 = 8$...
$b_2 = \frac{8k+1}{7}$...
k = 6
$ b_2 = 7$ ?

Comment: that can't be right since $b_2$ should be 6.

Comment: OK, $b_2=6$, but then you multiply by 2 *again* when you do $2f_2$. If you insist on $63b_2\equiv2\pmod8$, then you must do $f_1+f_2+f_3$, not $f_1+2f_2+3f+3$. The 2 is already there; you're putting it there twice.

Comment: nice ... I was able to get 498 thank you. And, the chat thing was an accident.. pressed the wrong button.

Comment: The usual way to thank someone here is to click in the check box next to the answer (if you are accepting the answer). But there's no rush --- a better answer might come along.

Answer (score 0):

$\overbrace{7a+1=8b+2=9c+3}^{(1)}\iff(8-1)a=8b+1=(8+1)c+2\iff\begin{align}8\,(a-b)=a+1\\8\,(b-c)=c\ +1\end{align}$ $a=8n-1$, and $c=8k-1$$\overset{(1)}\iff7n=9k$, the smallest solution being $n=9$, and $k=7$. But $n=a-b$, and $k=b-c$, so by replacing all of this into the original equation, we have $c=55$.

Answer (score 0):

If you exploit the innate structure, then those long arduous calculations can be replaced by a *minute of mental arithmetic!* $ $ Notice that

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&x\equiv 1\equiv \color{#c00}{-6}\pmod 7\\ && x\equiv 2\equiv \color{#c00}{-6}\pmod 8\\  &&x\equiv 3\equiv \color{#c00}{-6}\pmod 9\end{eqnarray} $$

which is true iff  $\ 7,8,9\mid x\!+\!\color{#c00}6,\,$ true iff $\ {\rm lcm}(7,8,9) = 7\cdot 8\cdot 9 = 504\,$ divides $\,x\!+\!6.\,$ Hence  $\, x\!+\!6 = 504n\,\Rightarrow\,x = 504 n - 6,\,$ hence the least positive $\, x = 504 - 6 = 498.\ \ $ **QED**